# Resize image on client before uploading

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html

I'm trying to upload a photo to my ASP.net website via Iphone 6s. As you can probably guess the file size is way to big and therefore the upload takes way to long. My program can already resize the file before storage but this is on the server side and therefor not a solution to my problem.

I would like to resize the image with JavaScript on the client. But then i have to upload the image to the server and the C# method that douse this looks like this

```
void imageUploader( byte[] image);
```

I have no idea how to feed that method the javaScript resize output...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to do that on client side. There are many plugins that uploads and then via callbacks returns the image resized.

Please have a look to this link http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/jQuery-Plugin-for-Client-Side-Image-Resizing-canvasResize.html